# Use one Array to filter result from another array, both are multidimensional

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, unset

I pull one array from a data and one array from an API.

API Array (array1)

```
...
[71] => Array
        (
            [id] => integer
            [name] => example_name
            [logo] => url_of_image
            [lang] => en
        )
...
```

Database API (array2)

```
    ...
Array(
    [0] => integer
    [1] => integer
}
    ...
```

I want to use array2 to find any instances of the ID in array1, if they exist then unset the key.

Array diff doesn't work with multidimensional.
There isn't a common key
The values are dynamic so i can't hard code them
Array filter won't take multi commands and doing a foreach results in an error

> Notice: Array to string conversion in

PHP 5.6.

```
foreach($array2 as $key => $value) {
   foreach($array1 as $key1 => $value1) {
      if ($value1 == $value) {
         unset($arrat2[$key])
      }
   }
}
```

I had this buried somewhere to filter out languages i thought i could stick a foreach inside the function but that throws an array to string conversion.

```
$filtered = array();
                    $filtered = array_filter($array1, function($el) { return ($el['lang'] == "en"); });
```

Something like:

```
        $result = array();
            foreach($array2 as $value) {
                $result = array_filter($array1, function($ee) { return ($ee['id'] != $value); });
            }
```

Results in:

> Notice: Undefined variable: value i

Var dumps array 2:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(8) "random integer"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(9) "random integer"
  }
}
```

var dumps array 1:

```
array(151) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(integer 1)
    ["name"]=>
    string(7) "example name 1"
    ["logo"]=>
    string(97) "image1.png"
    ["lang"]=>
    string(2) "en"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(integer 2)
    ["name"]=>
    string(10) "example name 2"
    ["logo"]=>
    string(100) "image2.png"
    ["lang"]=>
    string(2) "en"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(integer 3)
    ["name"]=>
    string(9) "example name 3"
    ["logo"]=>
    string(99) "image3.png"
    ["lang"]=>
    string(2) "en"
  }
```

great answer, also had to make sure my two values were both integers being compared.

Comment: Show your `foreach()`, I don't see why this approach wouldn't work if you are doing it correctly.

Comment: Why wouldn't `array_filter` work? _You_ supply the callback that decides if an element gets tossed or not.

Comment: @Rasclatt I know i am doing it wrong for sure, updated post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you want to do, this might help (you can provide more than 1 filter per line in `$array2`, lines are OR'ed while multiple conditions in one line are AND'ed):

```
<?php

$array1 = array(
    array(
        "id" => 1,
        "name" => "foo",
        "logo" => "foo-logo.png",
        "lang" => "es"
    ),
    array(
        "id" => 3,
        "name" => "bar",
        "logo" => "bar-logo.png",
        "lang" => "en"
    ),
    array(
        "id" => 7,
        "name" => "xyz",
        "logo" => "xyz-logo.png",
        "lang" => "it"
    ),
    array(
        "id" => 15,
        "name" => "aaa",
        "logo" => "aaa-logo.png",
        "lang" => "it"
    ),
    array(
        "id" => 23,
        "name" => "aaa",
        "logo" => "aaa-logo.png",
        "lang" => "es"
    ),
);

// Filter out entries with id #7 OR lang = en OR (name = "aaa" AND lang = "es")
$array2 = array(
    array("id" => 7),
    array("lang" => "en"),
    array("name" => "aaa", "lang" => "es")
);

echo "<pre>";

$filtered = array_filter($array1, function($e) use ($array2)
{
    foreach($array2 as $filters)
    {
        $doFilter = true;
        foreach($filters as $k => $v)
        {
            if (isset($e[$k]) && $e[$k] !== $v) {
                $doFilter = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if ($doFilter)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
});

var_dump($filtered);
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["name"]=>
    string(3) "foo"
    ["logo"]=>
    string(12) "foo-logo.png"
    ["lang"]=>
    string(2) "es"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(15)
    ["name"]=>
    string(3) "aaa"
    ["logo"]=>
    string(12) "aaa-logo.png"
    ["lang"]=>
    string(2) "it"
  }
}
```

Comment: I cant get this to work i think its because my IDs are strored like this: ```Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 32007412
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 131877902
        )

)```

Comment: That's exactly the structure that my `array2` has, what's the error?

Comment: Doesn't throw an error just doesn't filter anything

Comment: Can you `var_dump` your arrays? (input/`$array1` and filter/`$array2` in my case) Atleast a small portion would help.

Comment: updated main post the first result in both array 1 and array 2 is the same integer ID, is it because array 2 is a string not an integer?

Comment: It is a type-safe comparsion (`!==`), yes.

Comment: @ccKepy this worked i had to convert my string to an integer in array2. Wow thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have one too many loops.  Loop through the array you want to unset the key from, and test each value against the second array.

```
FOREACH ($array2){
$test_array[] = $id;
}
FOREACH ( $array1 AS $key => $array3){
  IF ( in_array($array3['id'],$test_array) ) {
    unset($array1[$key]);
  }
}
```

Comment: So i came across this on here somewhere else and this throws me a bracket error, even though all my brackets open and close correctly (not got 1 to many or 1 too short). [17-Jan-2017 20:31:01 America/Toronto] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '{' in //search.php on line 100 (line 100 being the unset line.)

Comment: @Keelan Did I understand correctly that you don't have `array1['id']` but that your ids are variables themselves....for example, `array1['id_this'] = 5;` would match and unset `array2['id_that'] = 5;`?

Comment: array1 carries multidemensional arrays that each contain at least an id. I have some ids stored in a databased which i retrieve to an array. I want those ids searching the in array1 and make the key unset. ID key is common in the arrays.

Comment: @Keelan So, you want to `unset($array1[$key])` when the value of `$array1[$key]['id]` is equal to any integer within `$array2[]`?

Comment: yes, however i have found out that the values inside array2 are strings not integers so this part of my problem ha.

Comment: Hmm so the only issue i think why this still doesn't work is because array2 also has sub arrays or id. 

```
array2 0 , id => blah
``` looking inside array1 0 , id => blah ```

Comment: Hopefully this is the last one...I added another Foreach loop to get the ['id'] from each sub array for $array2

Comment: `FOREACH ($array2 as $id){
$test_array[] = $id['id'];
}
FOREACH ( $array1 AS $key => $array3){
  IF ( in_array($array3['id'],$test_array) ) {
    unset($array1[$key]);
  }
}` this works